# Tensorflow keras: Which function in tf.keras.layer can repeat the array of the image on the third axes?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

In Tensorflow Keras, I want the input image in a defined shape (i.e., `(input_shape[0], input_shape[1], **512**)`). When I use the following code, I get this error: `ValueError: Output tensors to a Model must be the output of a TensorFlow Layer`.

```
input_mask = KL.Input(input_shape, name= "input_2")
x = tf.keras.backend.repeat_elements(x=input_mask, rep=512, axis=3)
_model_ = Model(inputs=input_mask, outputs=x, name='Mask_Model')
```

**Is there any alternative way?**
I used reshape also, but it was not successful as the number of elements are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap every operation with `Lambda` layer (or implement [custom layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models)):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

input_mask = tf.keras.layers.Input((2, 2, 3))
repeated = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(
    lambda x: tf.keras.backend.repeat_elements(x=x, rep=512, axis=3))(input_mask)
model =tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=input_mask, outputs=repeated)
```